# Order of Symplectic Matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, symplectic-linear-algebra

I'm going through Appendix 3 of Lax's Linear Algebra, and I'm not entirely sure why symplectic matrices **must** be of order $2n$.  He defines symplectic matrices as "linear maps that preserve a nonsingular bilinear alternating function of the form $(x,Ay)$, where $A$ is a real anti-self-adjoint matrix and $det A\ne0$.  It then follows that $A$ must be of even order $2n$".  However, I can't figure out why it must be of order $2n$, and as far as I can find online it's always just chalked up to "by definition".  My intuition is that it has something to do with pairing off basis vectors (i.e. pairing off $(e_1,Ae_2)$ etc), but I haven't been able to find any contradictions for the $n=3$ case (which we would expect if it had to be of even order).  It would seem to me that functions that are nonsingular and alternating must have even order, but I can't find out why.  What is the reason for this?

Comment: You say you haven't been able to find a contradiction for $n=3$. So can you give an example of a symplectic matrix of order $3$? Or, equivalently, can you give an example of nonsingular alternating form on a $3$-dimensional space? If you can do it for $n=2$ and $n=4$, and realize that you can't do it for $n=3$, that should teach you the reason.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut do you want to write that as an answer so I can give it a tick?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the statement you quote, $A$ must be a skew-symmetric matrix with nonzero determinant.

But skew-symmetric matrices of odd order have always determinant 0, because

$$\mathrm{det}(A)=\mathrm{det}(A^T)=\mathrm{det}(−A)=(−1)^n\mathrm{det}(A),$$

$n$ being the order of $A$.